# Отправить сообщение в вк через api

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, api

в чем дело, возвращает ошибку

```
{"error":{"error_code":5,"error_msg":"User authorization failed: access_token was given to another ip address.","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"messages.send"},{"key":"domain","value":"user"},{"key":"v","value":"5.37"}]}}
```

функция отправки

```
$url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send';
        $params = array(
            'domain' => 'maksim_drosdow',    // Кому отправляем
            'message' => $request->message,   // Что отправляем
            'access_token' => 'e42c016e16154291a4859055ba54375f',  // access_token можно вбить хардкодом, если работа будет идти из под одного юзера
            'v' => '5.37',
        );

        // В $result вернется id отправленного сообщения
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => http_build_query($params)
            )
        )));
        return $result;
```

Comment: в вашей ошибке уже все написано, что данный access_token, был выдан для другого айпи адресса.

Comment: а как такое может быть, если я привязал к сайту

Comment: Вам нужно запросить токен через сам сайт и ввести его. Как я понимаю, вы запросили его вручную через свой айпи, а не айпи сайта.

Comment: а через сайт просто вернуть вот так? return redirect(' https: / / oauth.vk.com/ authorize ?client_id=123123 &display=page& redirect_uri= https:// oauth.vk.com /blank.html&scope=offline,messages&response_type=token&v=5.37' ) или по другому как?